# Get an API key for civi update and mailings

Tags: api

My developer has asked me to provide an api key so that they can upgrade our version of civiCRM and set up cron and mailing system.  I have no idea how to do this....

Comment: Was "api key" their exact words? In order to do the upgrade they'll need either admin access to Civi (Drupal/Wordpress/etc), or they'll need access to run commands on the server, and in both those cases they'd be able to create an api key themselves. So I'm wondering if they're really asking for something else like admin access to the system?

Answer (score 2):

the API key sits in the database as a field for the CiviCRM contact. You can find it in the table civicrm_contact.

If you are not too technical and do not access your database directly on a regular basis the is an extension you can use called API Key (https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-key) which will show an additional tab for contacts if you are a sysadmin where you can see and add the API key for that user.

Does that answer your question?